# How to make a 3D plot in paraview with a time-axis?

Tags: paraview

After some simulations with fenics, I saved the results in `vtk` format, so that I can load it in ParaView. The results are 1D-data, that are time-dependent. In the end, it should look like these example figures, I found in some papers:

[image: Example figures]

This means one axis for space coordinates, one for the time and one for the actual data. ParaView shows me my data and with "warp by scalar" I get the desired result, however only for exactly one time step. Animating works too, but I do not want to create a video for 1D-data, when it looks much nicer in one 3D plot.

How can I add the time as additional axis in ParaView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This, I am afraid, is not supported currently. It's certainly a nice feature, however. I'd suggest making a feature request on the [ParaView Bug Tracker](http://paraview.org/Bug)

Comment: is it possible to simply make a spectogram-like visualization instead?